# What is Emirates airline current checked in baggage allowance from USA to Iran?

Tags: luggage

I’m planning a trip to Iran in December with Emirates airlines and would like to get a ticket online; however I’m so confused about the checked baggages allowance. Some agencies say I can take 3 checked in suitcases.  What is Emirates airline current checked in baggage allowance from USA to Iran ?

Comment: Emirates has significant information online [here](https://www.emirates.com/us/english/before-you-fly/baggage/) about baggage allowances. For example, an economy seat has different checked baggage limits than a first-class seat. In any event, this question is not answerable without knowing the routing you will choose (because other carriers with different limits may or will be involved) and what class of service you will select.